TotalView has no option in parallel system with OpenMP
enter image description here
From Debug a Parallel Program, then under Parallel System there are MPICH, OpenMPI etc, no OpenMP. How to debug OpenMP by choosing Parallel System ?
I looked into https://totalview.io/blog/openmp-debugging,
to debug an OpenMP program, but did not find where to popup OMPD tab.

What version of Totalview and which Compiler/openmp runtime do you use?

The only setting you usually need to start a debugging session for OpenMP is setting OMP_NUM_THREADS to more than a thread. If the OpenMP runtime supports OMPD, an up-to-date Totalview will show you the OMPD information.

version 2023.4.16

And which Compiler/OpenMP runtime?
